# How to know modbus address of miniElcor from Serial Port Monitor?

Tags: serial-port, modbus, plc

I have problem accessing the device miniElcor from ELGAS with Datacom-k3 as modbus interface.
The things is, i'm able to take the data with the manufacturer program called TELVES.
I want to take the data outside from telves program.

Here is the data that i take from Serial Port Monitor:

[Serial Port Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYmlG.png)

The data taken by pressing read Actual Values from TELVES program:

[Corresponding Data from Telves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WylPA.png)

I only need to read the value by using modbus, without telves.
Is there any suggestion on how to take the modbus address, and also knowing what is the datatype ?
Many Thanks..

Comment: It [looks like](https://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/Subsystems/Comm/PLC/Elgas.htm) the miniElcor does not use Modbus, rather a custom protocol called [ELGAR-2](https://doc.ipesoft.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=17282598#ELGAS2(CPII)-literatura).

Comment: You are right, the protocol itself using ELGAR-2. Is it possible to parse the data ? The data itself readable on modbus, but i didn't know how to parse it correctly as the image above shown.

Comment: @AraafArioSetyoGuritno in the brochure it states that it can do either ELGAS or Modbus. You need to check the manual for the serial port settings and then run a program which checks every server/slave address for the device. If you can, please update the post with this information. Have you ever heard of Modbus Poll? I think they offer a trial version, you could use that to verify your Modbus connection and the data format and then use whatever other device you want to get data from miniElcor.

Comment: The test above is using Modbus Protocol Setting of the device. I have already compared between Modbus and Elgas protocol. Both are readable at the modbus line and serial monitor program. Also the format is similar with few changes in the header. I already know the modbus address of the device, and it proven by connecting the telves to the device, also send by ping using the serial monitor. The weird part is i need to send 00 followed by modbus request to be able to get the response from the device. I already try the modbus parser with that input, but still no luck.

Comment: @AraafArioSetyoGuritno the manual is locked, so unless you link it somewhere accessible it'll be hard to help you further. You just might have to contact the company directly or build your own Modbus frame.